# How to organize a live search on a website?

Tags: craft3

I had a website on an old engine. And there I had a live search organized. Now I have decided to change the engine to CRAFT CMS and, accordingly, I need to organize a live search on the new engine.
I'll tell you how the live search was organized on the OLD ENGINE

**On the old engine** I had this HTML structure:

```
<form action="/games/" method="get">
    <div class="form">
        <input placeholder="Name" type="text" name="title" id="search_text">
        <button>GO</button>
    </div>
    <div id="results" class="search_results"></div>
</form>
```

**On the old engine**, I had this JQUERY handle:

```
$("#search_text").bind("keyup", function() {
    if(this.value.length >= 1){
        var searchString = $(this).val();
        var data = 'search='+ searchString;
        if(searchString) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "/functions/fast_search_result.php",
                data: data,
                success: function(html){
                    $("#results").addClass("infocus");
                    $("#results").html(html);
                }
            });
        }
    }else{
    $("#results").html('');
}
});
```

**On the old engine**, the file code **fast_search_result.php** was like this:

```
<?php
    $search_text = $_POST['search'];

    $link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'user', '123456789', 'name_db');

    $sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT `title`, `url` FROM `games` WHERE `title` LIKE `%".$search_text."%` ");
    $results = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
    foreach($results as $result){

        $title = $result['title'];
        $url = "/link/to/my/game/".$result['url']."/";

        echo "<div class='game'>";
            echo "<a href='".$url."' class='name'>".$title."</a>";
        echo "</div>";

    }
?>
```

That's the same thing I want to organize on CRAFT CMS. But only how to do it? I'm new to CRAFT CMS, I have an idea how to do it:

1. in the TWIG template, organize the form
2. Build a module that, when passing a POST to it, will work out this post and return the result. The module will work by URL, for example, /module/fast_search_result/
3. Well, leave the jquery handler the same, replacing in it only the path by which I will process the POST

If my idea is wrong or there is an easier way, please tell me. I will be glad)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wouldn't need to create or build a module, you can simply create the functionality with twig itself and use queries in the twig template:

https://craftcms.com/knowledge-base/search-form

If you want a live search you can use the sprig plugin and follow this:

https://putyourlightson.com/sprig/cookbook#search

Comment: Wow! I didn't expect it to be done so easily in this engine) tnx)))